# Speeding up phonegap app with cocoonjs

Tags: cordova, cocoonjs

Concoonjs is use to speed up html 5 game app.

I have a Phonegap/Cordova app(not game), but I am not sure by using Concoonjs will it speed up the performance?

Have anyone tried it before?

Comment: If you use the canvas element at all within your app then it definitely will improve that performance using their Webview+. Other than that I didn't notice any major performance changes, but it did make a few of my jquery animate calls a little choppy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried [cocoonjs](https://www.ludei.com/cocoonjs/) in a mobile payment application (rendering charts, ...) developed using Phonegap and i was quite satisfied with the results.

> [CocoonJS is also compatible with Apache Cordova/PhoneGap projects. You can provide your existing project and still improve your overall HTML5 execution speed, testing/debugging capabilities and deployment and monetization experience thanks to CocoonJS. Of course, you can still use existing Cordova plugins and even develop and use your own!](https://www.ludei.com/cocoonjs/)